# Регулярное выражение не работает как задумано

Tags: python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярка:
([ \t]{0,}[\d.]+[ \t]{0,}+[ \t]{0,}[\d.]+[ \t]{0,})

И тестовая строка:
1+22+33+45.5+0.2

Результат:

```
1+22
33+45.5
```

Не хватает:

```
22+33
45.5+0.2
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вам нужно `re.findall(r'(?=(?<![\d.])(?<!\d\.)(\d*\.?\d+[-+/*]\d*\.?\d+))', text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если надо вернуть все выражение, то

```
(?:[\t ]*[\-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?[\t ]*[+\-*/])+[\t ]*[\-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

Тут две основные части:
`(?:[\t ]*[\-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?[\t ]*[+\-*/])+` - повторяемая группа "число и оператор"
`[\t ]*[\-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - число, последнее в выражении (во входной строке)

`[\t ]*` это то же самое, что и `[ \t]{0,}`, но короче на 3 символа.

---

Если же надо вернуть пары с возвратом назад на позицию второго числа в каждой паре, то по-моему регуляркой не получится так.

Вместо этого, можно сначала найти все числа таким выражением:
`/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g`
, и затем уже кодом (в цикле) составить из них пары, типа

```
str = "1+22+33+45.5+0.2"
matches = re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?', str) 
for i in range(len(matches) - 1):
    print(matches[i], '+', matches[i + 1])
```

*<sub>(Сорри за качество кода, я не знаю Python)</sub>*

Comment: да, нужны пары. Я пытаюсь сделать обработчик арифметических выражений и вроде даже работает, с одной парой, но если передать три и более чисел, на выходе что-то типа 10+5...

Comment: @Евгений, Ну тогда второй вариант (извлечение всех чисел) должен быть даже удобнее. Операторы из строки тоже можно извлекать, например `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[\t ]*([+\-*/]?)` - вернет число и оператор. Только надо учитывать, что на последнем числе входной строки, вторая группа будет пуста.

Comment: Ваш код работает, но получаются просто пары. Я использовал вашу регулярку для подсчёта и немного доработал свою, чтобы искала она не пары, а только первую пару и дальше только знак и число. Дальше, результат конкат с тем, что осталось и так по новой в цикле по подсчёту вашей  регулярки.

Comment: Прочёл и понял, что ничего не понял. В общем, всё почти работает, только теперь новая проблема связанная с отрицательными числами - после того, как в выражении вычислилось число со знаком "-", дальше знак уходит в другую сторону результата, а вычисление меняет знак. Пример:
вычисление до -10 + 0.55, а после уже 10.55-, когда, ясно, что результат должен быть -9.55. Ну это уже наверное проблема в той регулярке, что вырезает ту часть выражения, что уже вычислилась.

Comment: @Евгений, А почему бы просто не скормить входную строку `eval`, проверив ее регуляркой из первого варианта? Проверка ведь гарантирует что вычисление строки безопасно... Собственно, для таких целей `eval` и существует (математические выражения считать).

Comment: По скорости почти одинаково, с eval быстрее в два раза, регулярки оказались медленнее eval. Просто хочется самому, или хотя бы с чьей-нибудь помощью, понять как оно должно работать. Всё равно спс

Comment: Не доверяю eval'у, но видно, пока я не разберусь, у меня нет выбора. Даже с проверкой, переопределением глобальных переменных и затиранием buildins'ов, очень не доверяю. Не возможно eval полностью изолировать в Python'е. И, на сколько я знаю (хотя могу и ошибаться), в JavaScript тоже.